# How to get HTML element node value in TinyMCE editor using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tinymce-4

How to get the node name value using javascript or jquery in TinyMCE editor.

I could get only the nodeName. Here is my code below I tried,

```
var ed = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
var errorNode = ed.selection.getNode().nodeName;
alert(errorNode);
```

I have tried with jquery text() and value() but cannot fetch the node name value in HTML tags.

I just want to retrieve the value from HTML tags.
For example i have span tags `<span color="error">That's great</span>`

Could anyone please give me suggestion or help on this topic

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Getting the text value of a node in pure JS is done by `getNode().textContent` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: @Thomas Altman That's working. But, in my html source textContent are entities(unicode) look  like below <span class="error">necessarily&#8212;there</span>. I want to extract with entities value

Answer (score 1):

As Thomas Altmann suggested in the comment, you can get the DOM Node value by using `textContent`, or `innerHTML` and `innerText`. So you can do it like this:

```
var ed = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
var text = ed.selection.getNode().textContent; // or innerHTML and innerText
alert(text); // That's great
```

And if you want to get all the editor content without HTML tags, you can use `getContent` method:

```
window.tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({ format: 'text' })
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Yes i can. But, in my html source text content are entities with that value (unicode) look like below <span class="error">necessarily&#8212;there</span>. I want to extract with entities value. Is it possible to extract that too ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Not sure what you mean by extract with it? Do you mean to convert it from Unicode to HTML?